# Sorting Attr(Date) in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Im trying to sort a tabular report in tableau which contains attr(date) in the rows shelf. When Im trying to sort it by latest date first, I get the following screen :

[image]

Instead of this screen  :

[image]

And if I try to sort the data based on any other field using the sort by field option then it doesn't give correct data.

Comment: You cannot sort by an attribute field. Explained at https://community.tableau.com/thread/117749 and https://www.interworks.com/blog/tcostello/2014/05/15/attr-tableaus-attribute-function-explained. With a little more info about your data source, perhaps we could suggest an alternate approach.

Comment: Hi Sam, What could be a turnaround to this. We are using redshift connections in the backend. I tried pulling up Exact date for my date column and then sort it, but still shows up incorrect results